# How to convert 3D coordinates into 2D (X,Y) for positioning text div just below the 3d game object

Tags: javascript, webgl

I need to position on screen just below the 3d player the DIVSet in correct X,Y position, but I am not sure how to convert x,y,z  into x,y coordinates.

```
 this.player = player => {
    const pos = interpolate(player.position, player.movementVector)

    resetDivSets()

    calcViewMatrix()
    mat4Translate(viewMatrix, -pos.x * glScale, -3.1 * glScale, pos.y * glScale)
    mat4RotateY(viewMatrix, playerRotation(player, player.drawMovementVector))
    gl.uniformMatrix4fv(uVmatrix, false, viewMatrix)
    gl.uniform3f(uAmbientColor, 1, 1, 1)
    gl.drawElements(gl.TRIANGLES, builtSprites.player.ibCount, gl.UNSIGNED_SHORT, builtSprites.player.ibStart * 2)


// compute a clipspace position

        var clipspace =  WHAT TO HAVE HERE??;

        // divide X and Y by W just like the GPU does.
        clipspace[0] /= clipspace[3];
        clipspace[1] /= clipspace[3];

        // convert from clipspace to pixels
        var pixelX = (clipspace[0] *  0.5 + 0.5) * gl.canvas.width;
        var pixelY = (clipspace[1] * -0.5 + 0.5) * gl.canvas.height;

    addDivSet("Player Name under player object", pixelX , pixelY);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This article covers it](https://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-text-html.html)

Basically

```
    // compute a clipspace position
    var modelRelativePosition = [0, 0, 0, 1];  // NOTE!! w = 1
    var clipspace = m4.transformVector(uVmatrix, modelRelativePosition);

    // divide X and Y by W just like the GPU does.
    clipspace[0] /= clipspace[3];
    clipspace[1] /= clipspace[3];

    // convert from clipspace to pixels
    var pixelX = (clipspace[0] *  0.5 + 0.5) * gl.canvas.width;
    var pixelY = (clipspace[1] * -0.5 + 0.5) * gl.canvas.height;

    // position the div
    div.style.left = Math.floor(pixelX) + "px";
    div.style.top  = Math.floor(pixelY) + "px";
```

where transformVector is something like

```
  function transformVector(m, v, dst) {
    dst = new Float32Array(4);
    for (var i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
      dst[i] = 0.0;
      for (var j = 0; j < 4; ++j) {
        dst[i] += v[j] * m[j * 4 + i];
      }
    }
    return dst;
  }
```

And if you want to offset in 2d just add that at the bottom

```
    div.style.left = Math.floor(pixelX + offsetX) + "px";
    div.style.top  = Math.floor(pixelY + offsetY) + "px";
```

```js
const gl = document.createElement('canvas').getContext('webgl');
// use the identity matrix as a test
var uVmatrix = [
  1, 0, 0, 0,
  0, 1, 0, 0,
  0, 0, 1, 0,
  0, 0, 0, 1,
];

// compute a clipspace position
var modelRelativePosition = [0, 0, 0, 1];  // NOTE! w = 1
var clipspace = transformVector(uVmatrix, modelRelativePosition);

// divide X and Y by W just like the GPU does.
clipspace[0] /= clipspace[3];
clipspace[1] /= clipspace[3];

// convert from clipspace to pixels
var pixelX = (clipspace[0] * 0.5 + 0.5) * gl.canvas.width;
var pixelY = (clipspace[1] * -0.5 + 0.5) * gl.canvas.height;

// position the div
//div.style.left = Math.floor(pixelX) + "px";
//div.style.top = Math.floor(pixelY) + "px";
console.log(Math.floor(pixelX) + "px", Math.floor(pixelY) + "px");

function transformVector(m, v, dst) {
  dst = new Float32Array(4);
  for (var i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
    dst[i] = 0.0;
    for (var j = 0; j < 4; ++j) {
      dst[i] += v[j] * m[j * 4 + i];
    }
  }
  return dst;
}
```

Comment: Thanks but what would be  m4, its giving compiler error

Comment: It seems clipspace is Null;  var clipspace = transformVector(uVmatrix, modelRelativePosition,gdst);

Comment: your math library is your own thing, not part of WebGL. You can't expect people to understand your math library if you don't post it. Posted code that runs in the question. You can also go read the linked article.

Comment: sorry , there is also camera position, and I cannot get it to work, the link was excellent!

Comment: The code you posted only has `uVmatrix`. If you have other matrices used to calculate the position then you need to multiply those together using your math library to produce a single matrix. Usually that's `projectionMatrix * viewMatrix * someCombinationOfMatricesForTheModelMatrix`